# Correct directory structure for a Go Project?

Tags: go

I'm relatively new to Go and I've recently created a project that's going up on GitHub. I've tried to follow guides but there's a pressing question of why my binaries end up in `src/`?

My layout is like this:

```
ssm/ - Name of project
    LICENSE
    README.md
    src/ - Source Code
        files.go - All my source code is here.
        src - The compiled binary ends up here
    bin/ - Binaries
```

I set my `$GOPATH` to `~/Documents/Programming/Go/`. From my gopath, I can't type `go build ssm` because it `cannot find package`. If I cd into the directory, it complains it `can't load package: package .: no Go source files`.

I have to actually go into src and compile there, which means the binary isn't in `bin/`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `echo $GOPATH` show the directory as you expect? Is the ssm directory inside $GOPATH ? Does `go install` works inside src ?

Comment: `$GOPATH` shows the right directory. Yeah, the project is in `$GOPATH/ssm`. Install doesn't work: `go install: no install location for directory /Users/mark/Documents/Programming/Go/ssm/src outside GOPATH`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/GithubCodeLayout

To be compatible with `go get`, your project's package name needs to be fully-qualified under the github.com domain:

```
$GOPATH/
    src/github.com/<user>/ssm/
        .git
        LICENSE
        README.md
        files.go
    bin/
```

Note that the base of the git repository (.git) is not the same as the `$GOPATH`.

Also, `go build <package>` will output a compiled executable to the current directory.  If you want the exe to go to `bin/`, use `go install <package>` instead.

Comment: I don't think having github.com/user as a package directory is strictly necessary. It is if you want to import third party packages hosted in github, or if you want other people to use easily your library. If you have just imports from the native library it should compile just as well if under /src. Of course since eventually you will want to use external packages he may just do it so now...

Comment: OK, an alternative is to move files.go to `$XYZ/ssm/src/ssm/files.go` and set `GOPATH=$XYZ/ssm` so that `go build ssm` will work as expected.

Comment: This works! Thank's a lot. Incase anyone's wondering, `go install` puts the binary in bin/. `go build` makes one in the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

Your go code you can kept in a workspace. A workspace contains many source files **(git, hg, svm, etc.)**. The Go tool understand the layout. We don't require **Makefile** or **build.xml** here. The basic directory layout is everything. If in any case if you are going to change the file layout, accordingly you need to change the build.

This is the general structure you can follow,

$GOPATH/

```
src/
    github.com/username/repo/
        mypkg/
            mysrc1.go
            mysrc2.go
        cmd/mycmd/
            main.go
bin/
    mycmd
```

And, **this is the standard workspace**

$GOPATH/

```
bin/fixhub                              # installed binary
pkg/darwin_amd64/                       # compiled archives
    code.google.com/p/goauth2/oauth.a
    github.com/...
src/                                    # source repositories
    code.google.com/p/goauth2/
        .hg
        oauth                           # used by package go-github
        ...
    github.com/
        golang/lint/...                 # used by package fixhub
            .git
        google/go-github/...            # used by package fixhub
            .git
        dsymonds/fixhub/
            .git
            client.go
            cmd/fixhub/fixhub.go        # package main
```

**go get** fetch many repositories whereas **go install** builds a binary out of them. It's convenient and easy to go for go development quickly. And, everyone in the go community follows the same. This puts **src**, **bin** and **pkg** into the home directory. And, **$HOME/bin is already in our path before creating our workspace.**